# unable to open web service tester page with jdk8 and netbeans 8

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, netbeans-8

I wrote a simple web service program but I can not test it on glassfish 4.0 web server .
When I Test Web service I see this message : 
Make sure the service has been deployed successfully, and the server is running.

I can see it in list of deployed web services on glassfish web server . 
and I add this file to \jdk1.8.0\jre\lib to fix the problem.

jaxp.properties

`javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = All`
But it doesn't work

Also I see this error in url of tester page :

```
lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'bundle' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answer :
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html#extschema
You should configure IDE and Glassfish server directly .
With special thanks to [Pablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919228/pablo%22Pablo%22)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

1. From NetBeans IDE 8, deploy your web application in order to start GlassFish (right-click on your web project and choose Deploy)
2. Open the GlassFish console on your browser (`http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf` if you are working locally with default configuration)
3. Create a new JVM option with value: -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all (I recomend you to read https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/administration-guide.pdf at page 119). Don't forget to save it.
4. Restart GlassFish (by clicking on the message near upper left corner)

That must be enough... so, try to test your web service again.

I don't know where GlassFish is saving that change...

Sorry for my english :)