# Unable to open web service tester page-Glassfish

Tags: netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

when i tried to test web service EJBModule project, but i got following error.

```
unable to open web service tester page
http://localhost:8080/Test/Test?Tester
Make sure the service has been deployed successfully, and the server is running.
```

I checked ports of my computer using TCPview and no program is using this port.
The service also has been deployed successfully.

Comment: Please, here you can have a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147548/unable-to-open-web-service-tester-page-with-jdk8-and-netbeans-8 regards, Marcelle